# A special double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

For any given $p, q$ natural numbers and $x_0, y_0 \in [0,1]$, I want to compute the double integral $I_{p,q} = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{ x^p y^q}{ \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2} } dx \, dy$

Wolfram online does not give an answer on this, is possible to compute it via some formula?
I guess there is some recursion going on due to integration by parts on the monomials at the numerator.

Comment: Any information on the values of $x_0$ and $y_0$? If these are both between $0$ and $1$ the integral may not behave nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematica tells us that

$$\int _0^1\int _0^1\frac{x^p y^q}{\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(x-y_0)^2}}dxdy=\begin{cases}
\frac{F_{1}(1+p,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},2+p,\frac{1-i}{x_0-i y_0},\frac{1+i}{x_0+i y_0})}{(1+p)(1+q)\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}},  & x_0<y_0 \\
\frac{F_{1}(1+p,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},2+p,\frac{1+i}{x_0+i y_0},\frac{1-i}{x_0-i y_0})}{(1+p)(1+q)\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}},  & x_0\ge y_0
\end{cases}$$

Assumptions for the integration are $\{x_0, y_0\in [0,1],p\in \mathbb{Z}\land p>0,q\in \mathbb{Z}\land q>0\}$

**Hint:** $F_{1}(a,b_1,b_2,c,x,y)$ is the Appell hypergeometric function of two variables ([see F1](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/hypergeometric.html#appellf1)).

Here is a python code to compute the integral:

```
from mpmath import *
mp.dps = 25
mp.pretty = True

def integral1(p, q, x0, y0):
    if x0 < y0:
        x = mpc(1, -1) / mpc(x0, -y0)
        y = mpc(1, +1) / mpc(x0, +y0)
    else:
        x = mpc(1, +1) / mpc(x0, +y0)
        y = mpc(1, -1) / mpc(x0, -y0)

    denominator = (1 + p) * (1 + q) * mp.sqrt(x0**2 + y0**2)
    return appellf1(1 + p, 0.5, 0.5, 2 + p, x, y) / denominator

value1 = integral1(1, 2, 2, 1)
print(value1)
```

Numerical integration also confirm the above formula.

Comment: Many thanks, could you update your answer by taking as limits of integration -1 and 1 for both x and y?